# Setting height of ImageView in Horizontal LinearLayout

Tags: android

I have a horizontal linear layout with an ImageView and a TextView. My text can vary in length. So I want my ImageView to have the same height as the TextView. Could anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achive this with the help of RelativeLayout and in that just set the alignTop and alignBottom attributes of imageview to textview.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextViewsdfljasldfjl ;kasjdflkajslkdfasdfjlasjdfklasdklfjlkasdflkasdlkflkasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```